# JSONLoader raycaster & collision meshes - three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision, intersection, raycasting

I'm using raycaster to see if I hit a mesh with the mouse ( or touch ) the object is thin and I could do with increasing the size of whatever can be intersected with the Ray. As with games objects, (using three.js) can I add my own collision mesh, that obviously does not render, but triggers the Ray?

[image]

So, when my ray hits the (invisible) pink cylinder that is associated with the original mesh, it triggers the intersect.

I can't simply make another mesh that is grouped with the original and make it visible = false; or opacity = 0; that dosen't work. I'm looking for something 'built in' ( if it exists )

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add a collision mesh to your scene that responds to raycasting, but does not render.

To do so, add your collision mesh as a child of your mesh, and set the visibility of the collision mesh's *material* to false.

```
collisionMeshMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    visible: false
} );
```

The collision mesh will not render, but it will respond to raycasting.

three.js r.74

Comment: Thanks for these, I will test and get back.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a collection of clickable meshes without adding them to the scene.
Then just raycast against this collection: `raycaster.intersectObjects(collection);`

You may have to keep them "synchronized" with their parent object though.